# Pytorch LSTM model's loss not decreasing

Tags: nlp, pytorch, lstm, loss-function

I am writing a program that make use of the build in LSTM in the Pytorch, however the loss is always around some numbers and does not decrease significantly.
My model look like this:

```
class LSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, output_size, hidden_dim, n_layers):
        super(LSTM, self).__init__()
        # Defining some parameters
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        self.n_layers = n_layers
        #Defining the layers
        # LSTM Layer
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_dim, n_layers, batch_first=True)
        for name, param in self.lstm.named_parameters():
            if 'weight_ih' in name:
                torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(param.data)
            elif 'weight_hh' in name:
                torch.nn.init.orthogonal_(param.data)
            elif 'bias' in name:
                param.data.fill_(0)
        # Fully connected layer
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_size)
        torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.fc.weight)
        self.softmax = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        batch_size = x.size(0)

        # Initializing hidden state for first input using method defined below
        hidden = self.init_hidden(batch_size)

        # Passing in the input and hidden state into the model and obtaining outputs
        out, hidden = self.lstm(x, hidden)
        
        # print(out[-1])
        
        # Reshaping the outputs such that it can be fit into the fully connected layer
        out = out.contiguous().view(-1, self.hidden_dim)
        out = self.fc(out)
        out = self.softmax(out)
        
        return out, hidden

    def init_hidden(self, batch_size):
        # This method generates the first hidden state of zeros which we'll use in the forward pass
        # We'll send the tensor holding the hidden state to the device we specified earlier as well
        device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
        hidden = (torch.zeros(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim, dtype=torch.double, device=device),
                  (torch.zeros(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim, dtype=torch.double, device=device)))
        return hidden


lstm = LSTM(300, 2, 2, 7)
lstm = lstm.double()
lstm.to(device)
criterion = nn.NLLLoss()

learning_rate = 0.6
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(lstm.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
```

And here is the function for each training sample

```
def epoch(x, y):
    global lstm, criterion, learning_rate, optimizer
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    x = torch.unsqueeze(x, 1)
    output, hidden = lstm(x)
    output = torch.unsqueeze(output[-1], 0)
    loss = criterion(output, y)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    return output, loss.item()
```

And the loss in the training looks like this:

[image]

Is there anything wrong with these codes? Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: my immediate suspect would be the learning rate, try reducing it by several orders of magnitude, you may want to try the default value 1e-3

a few more tweaks that may help you debug your code:
-  you don't have to initialize the hidden state, it's optional and LSTM will do it internally
- calling optimizer.zero_grad() right before loss.backward() may prevent some unexpected consequences

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Roni. The problem turns out to be the misunderstanding of the batch size and other features that defining an nn.LSTM. Now I'm working on it.